# vpn connection via socks proxy

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, socks

I can't seem to get a transparent proxy working in openvz. So instead I would like the VPN client to give me back a local socks proxy (ip:port). Is this possible in OpenVPN or any other VPN client program on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any "real" VPN software that supports this. The typical way you do something like this (the poor man's VPN, if you will) is with SSH dynamic port forwarding -- some VPN services do provide SSH port forwarding as part of their offering. Then you just run something like

```
ssh -D <port> <vpn_server_hostname_or_ip>
```

and use `localhost:<port>` as the SOCKS proxy.